# Windows Phone 8.1 emulators is not available in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-phone-emulator

I have successfully running windows phone 8 emulator with Visual Studio 2013. But after final update I could not find my Virtual Machine in Hyper-V manager. I have updated to 8.1 and also get the latest update possible. But still nothing is there. And because of that windows phone application is failing with error no hardware virualization error.

Is there any way out or if I can install that manually ?

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I'm sorry, but my Windows 8.1 is localized in Italian, so I might not be able to give the exact name for the items I am going to mention.

1) Go to the control panel, the desktop/classic version of it. I usually reach it by clicking on the start button and typing "control panel", until it appears.

2) Click on the item you normally use to install/remove software, should be "Programs and Features", but I am not sure. In any event, it should be the one under the power management options.

3) On the left side of the installed applications' list, click on the last entry of the list, the one with the shield on the left. Should be something like "Enable/Disable Windows Features".

4) Look for "Hyper-V" and make sure it is enabled

Hope this helps

Comment: Hyper-V manager is working only. I was having emulators also when there was windows 8 but not they are not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the emulators manually from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43719